# rendering foreign field in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a model where a field references a foreign key from another model as:

```
class DummyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)        
    image_type = models.ForeignKey(ImageTypeModel)  # Foreign key

    class Meta:
        db_table = "dummy"
```

The parent model is also simple:

```
class ImageTypeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dims = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "imagetypes"
```

Now, I attempt to render a record in a form and for that purpose I am using `django-crispy-forms`. So, I have:

```
class DummyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DummyModel
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'image_type']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DummyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-10'
        #self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('name'),
            Field('description'),
            Field('image_type'))
```

The `image_type` field renders as a drop-down list which is perfect but instead of the name of the image types, the entries are all labelled `ImageTypeModel`. Is there a mechanism so that I can **display** the corresponding name from the `ImageTypeModel` record but when the form is saved it saves the primary key rather than the name.

Comment: Have you implemented the `__unicode__` method (for python 2) or `__str__` (python 3) inside the `ImageTypeModel` model?

Comment: hmmmmmm...nope. Ok, had no idea that I had to do it!

Comment: That did the trick! Do you want to write it as an answer so that I can accept it>

Comment: Did it already  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement the `__unicode__` (python 2) or `__str__` (python 3) method inside the model.

Like this:

```
class ImageTypeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dims = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "imagetypes"

    # For Python 2
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    # For Python 3
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```